# Is there any way to avoid multiple joins in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables. Product table contain my skus which has these columns: id, name, sku, image

my other table is my warehouse_in_and_out which has: id, date_time, sku_id, inbound_outbound, adjustment. date_time and sku_id are unique together so I have only 1 row for each sku each day. Also my inbound_outbound and adjustment is an array of integers.

I want to get inbound_outbound for each day in a date range for each sku and also want to have sum of all inbound_outbound for all rows of each sku

I have came up with something like this:

```
SELECT P.ID ,SKU,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/31/2021' THEN WARE.INBOUND_OUTBOUND
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS INBOUND_OUTBOUND_1,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/31/2021' THEN WARE.ADJUSTMENT
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS ADJUSTMENT_1,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/30/2021' THEN WARE.INBOUND_OUTBOUND
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS INBOUND_OUTBOUND_2,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/30/2021' THEN WARE.ADJUSTMENT
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS ADJUSTMENT_2
FROM PRODUCTS AS P
LEFT JOIN WAREHOUSE_IN_AND_OUT AS WARE ON WARE.SKU_ID = P.ID
WHERE P.STORE_ID IN ('1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4',
        '5')
GROUP BY P.ID, SKU
ORDER BY SKU
```

My result in json is:

```
{
    id: '1',
    sku: 'ABC',
    inbound_outbound_1: null,
    adjustment_1: null,
    inbound_outbound_2: [
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      5000, 4960
    ],
    adjustment_2: null
  }
```

when I want to add my total to this sql I get 2 same rows:

```
SELECT P.ID ,SKU,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/31/2021' THEN WARE.INBOUND_OUTBOUND
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS INBOUND_OUTBOUND_1,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/31/2021' THEN WARE.ADJUSTMENT
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS ADJUSTMENT_1,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/30/2021' THEN WARE.INBOUND_OUTBOUND
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS INBOUND_OUTBOUND_2,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/30/2021' THEN WARE.ADJUSTMENT
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS ADJUSTMENT_2,
    COALESCE(
                    (SELECT SUM(I)
                        FROM UNNEST(WARE.INBOUND_OUTBOUND) AS I),0)::INTEGER AS TOTAL
FROM PRODUCTS AS P
LEFT JOIN WAREHOUSE_IN_AND_OUT AS WARE ON WARE.SKU_ID = P.ID
WHERE P.STORE_ID IN ('1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4',
        '5')
GROUP BY P.ID, SKU, INBOUND_OUTBOUND
ORDER BY SKU
```

my result is:

```
[
  {
    id: '1',
    sku: 'ABC',
    total: -4,
    inbound_outbound_1: [ 52, -56 ],
    adjustment_1: null,
    inbound_outbound_2: null,
    adjustment_2: null
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    sku: 'ABC',
    total: 188520,
    inbound_outbound_1: null,
    adjustment_1: null,
    inbound_outbound_2: [
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      5000, 4960
    ],
    adjustment_2: null
  }
]
```

but I want to get only one row for each sku. my expected result is:

```
[
  {
    id: '1',
    sku: 'ABC',
    total: 188516,
    inbound_outbound_1:  [ 52, -56 ],
    adjustment_1: null,
    inbound_outbound_2: [
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960, 4960,
      5000, 4960
    ],
    adjustment_2: null
  }
]
```

Thanks to Jon I have implemented my schema inside [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=eb3838e3baeae1e6e0f98ebf45cbaadd)

I want to have 6 and 8 result in one result if thats possible. I don't want to have many results for each sku like in 7 parag. I want to have total for each sku

Comment: Your result of `GROUP BY P.ID, SKU, INBOUND_OUTBOUND` is not guaranteed to contain one row (group) per `SKU`.  You'll need to provide a more complete logical description of the problem, plus all the detail requested in every other question you've asked.  I won't repeat that here.  Explain your entire goal, and please relate that to the logic used in your SQL, especially your `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: have you tried removing `INBOUND_OUTBOUND` from your `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @JonArmstrong What should I explain more? Can you please specify? I would be happy to explain it. I mean I said what our my table columns and Whats my desired result.

Comment: 1) Results without the precise input data which caused those results is often not sufficient.  2) It's important to show the constraints in each table, so, for instance, we can tell if `SKU` is _guaranteed_ unique over the rows in a table.  3) the actual schema, which contains the precise types, so that your SQL (and any solutions) can be tested.  Remember, I provided this for you, but I had to guess.  Please update the fiddle I provided to correct any type issues and adjust the data to allow testing your SQL.

Comment: From one of the questions you asked about the same issue, this is the kind of test case you should provide, showing the scheme, data (via inserts) and actual results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=682d87d5ce3e5932fdf90c8544d7f8ae   You will want to also provide expected results and how (logically) we can derive that result from your data.  You don't need to know the SQL.  But you do need to understand your own problem logically.

Comment: @JonArmstrong Thank you for the information, i didn't know about dbfiddle. I just updated my question. hope this time I explained more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a lateral join rather than a sub-query in your SELECT...

```
SELECT P.ID, P.SKU,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/31/2021' THEN WARE.INBOUND_OUTBOUND
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS INBOUND_OUTBOUND_1,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/31/2021' THEN WARE.ADJUSTMENT
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS ADJUSTMENT_1,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/30/2021' THEN WARE.INBOUND_OUTBOUND
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS INBOUND_OUTBOUND_2,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/30/2021' THEN WARE.ADJUSTMENT
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS ADJUSTMENT_2,
       MAX(CASE
    WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/29/2021' THEN WARE.INBOUND_OUTBOUND
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS INBOUND_OUTBOUND_3,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/29/2021' THEN WARE.ADJUSTMENT
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS ADJUSTMENT_3,
    COALESCE(SUM(I.SUM_I),0)::INTEGER AS TOTAL
FROM PRODUCTS AS P
LEFT JOIN WAREHOUSE_IN_AND_OUT AS WARE ON WARE.SKU_ID = P.ID
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT SUM(I) SUM_I FROM UNNEST(WARE.INBOUND_OUTBOUND) I) I
GROUP BY P.ID, SKU
ORDER BY SKU
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9f94ecd3f1c38ab01eca06699c980424

Answer (score 1):

While @MatBailie has provided a very nice solution, I thought I'd add an example of a direct / simple combination of your two statements.  This can be helpful in lots of other cases as well.

[The fiddle, with both solutions](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=30f75888891c7b48b58f2b45ca922f59)

```
WITH cte1 AS (
         SELECT P.ID, P.SKU
              , MAX(CASE
                      WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/31/2021' THEN WARE.INBOUND_OUTBOUND
                          ELSE NULL
                      END
                   ) AS INBOUND_OUTBOUND_1
              , MAX(CASE
                      WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/31/2021' THEN WARE.ADJUSTMENT
                          ELSE NULL
                      END
                   ) AS ADJUSTMENT_1
              , MAX(CASE
                      WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/30/2021' THEN WARE.INBOUND_OUTBOUND
                          ELSE NULL
                      END
                   ) AS INBOUND_OUTBOUND_2
              , MAX(CASE
                     WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/30/2021' THEN WARE.ADJUSTMENT
                          ELSE NULL
                      END
                   ) AS ADJUSTMENT_2
              , MAX(CASE
                      WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/29/2021' THEN WARE.INBOUND_OUTBOUND
                          ELSE NULL
                      END
                   ) AS INBOUND_OUTBOUND_3
              , MAX(CASE
                     WHEN DATE_TIME = '12/29/2021' THEN WARE.ADJUSTMENT
                          ELSE NULL
                      END
                   ) AS ADJUSTMENT_3
           FROM PRODUCTS AS P
           LEFT JOIN WAREHOUSE_IN_AND_OUT AS WARE ON WARE.SKU_ID = P.ID
          GROUP BY P.ID, SKU
          ORDER BY SKU
     )
   , cte2 AS (
         SELECT sku, SUM(total) as total
           FROM (
                  SELECT P.SKU
                       , COALESCE(
                                    (SELECT SUM(I)
                                       FROM UNNEST(WARE.INBOUND_OUTBOUND) AS I
                                    )
                                    , 0
                                 )::INTEGER AS TOTAL
                    FROM PRODUCTS AS P
                    LEFT JOIN WAREHOUSE_IN_AND_OUT AS WARE ON WARE.SKU_ID = P.ID
                   ORDER BY SKU
                ) AS test
          GROUP BY SKU
     )
SELECT cte1.*, cte2.total
  FROM cte1
  JOIN cte2 
    ON cte1.SKU = cte2.SKU
;
```